# How to make "portable" web app with Apache, Php, and Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, webserver

I want to run a web application on a Windows computer but because of some reasons, I don't want to install a web stack like Xampp on that machine.

The web app is placed in a folder and inside of it, there are Apache, PHP, the database like MySQL or PostgreSQL, and the web source. If we want to access it, there is just a shortcut in the Desktop, and when we click that, the browser is opened and point to an URL with a particular port like localhost:8888. And the web app is opened.

I just want to put that folder in an installer. And the installer just extracts it to system folder and create a shortcut on the desktop.

I ask this because I have ever seen stuff like this. It used PostgreSQL. Simply like what I've just explained above.

If you know how to make it works, you may want to help me. Your answers will be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a strange approach to something you can achieve much easier: create a docker based container of your setup, there are templates for a LAMP stack available. That allows to use the setup _without_ having to install it into a system which always creates lots of issues.

Comment: Another, also much easier approach would be to use the http server built into php itself instead of the apache http server and to use a SQLite database instead of MySQL. That way you get around having to install _anything_. That would actually be what people usually refer to when mentioning a "portable" software.

Comment: There were a software called MOWES  - it was a portable web server, but it was supported only until PHP 5.3
So, depending of your tasks, maybe you still could use it, or find a way to update PHP version on this server.

Answer (score 1):

You have three way to provide your web application as a software application

1. you can create portable server in pen drive server start by your application present on desktop icon.
2. you can create installer using Microsoft Installer which install all the requirement in one go then point ini file to your source code folder. This will let desktop icon to start xammp and run your application.(only applicable for window)
3. write python script to install web server using CMD and Terminal. then python script point ini to your source folder  . Generate shortcut for server start command and launch browser with url.

we already provide Lab application in pen drive based server